# PhraseMatcher to match in a different token attribute

Tags: nlp, spacy

We would like to match a set of phrases using PhraseMatcher. However we whould like to match not only on the verbatim text, but a normalized version of the input. For instance, lower case, with the accents removed, etc.

We have tried to add a custom attibute to the Token, and use it in the init of the PhraseMatcher to match it but, it did not work.

We could transform the text using a custom pipeline but we want to keep the original text to be able to use other components of spacy.

```py
def deaccent(text):
    ...
    return modified_text


def get_normalization(doc):
    return deaccent(doc.text)


Token.set_extension('get_norm', getter=get_normalization)


patterns_ = [{"label": "TECH", "pattern": "java"}]
ruler = EntityRuler(nlp, phrase_matcher_attr="get_norm")
ruler.add_patterns(patterns_)


nlp.add_pipe(ruler)
```

What is the way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since EntityRuler is based on PhraseMatcher, I copy here a working example with Spacy v2.2.0. Follow the comments to understand how to work with "NORM" attribute from tokens.

At the end, you can see how the word "FÁCIL" matches the pattern "facil", since it has been normalized.

```py
import re
import spacy 
from unicodedata import normalize
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Span
from spacy.lang.es import Spanish

# Define our custom pipeline component that overwrites the custom attribute "norm" from tokens
class Deaccentuate(object):
    def __init__(self, nlp):
        self._nlp = nlp

    def __call__(self, doc):
        for token in doc:
            token.norm_ = self.deaccent(token.lower_)  # write norm_ attribute!
        return doc

    @staticmethod
    def deaccent(text):
        """ Remove accentuation from the given string """
        text = re.sub(
            r"([^n\u0300-\u036f]|n(?!\u0303(?![\u0300-\u036f])))[\u0300-\u036f]+", r"\1",
            normalize("NFD", text), 0, re.I
        )
        return normalize("NFC", text)


nlp = Spanish()
# Add component to pipeline
custom_component = Deaccentuate(nlp)
nlp.add_pipe(custom_component, first=True, name='normalizer')
# Initialize matcher with patterns to be matched 
matcher =  PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="NORM")  # match in norm attribute from token
patterns_ = nlp.pipe(['facil', 'dificil'])
matcher.add('MY_ENTITY', None, *patterns_)

# Run an example and print results
doc = nlp("esto es un ejemplo FÁCIL")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = Span(doc, start, end, label=match_id)
    print("MATCHED: " + span.text)
```

This bug was fixed in release v2.1.8
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4002